# How to get Asset type and Reference variable name and value in Ymal file for Dynamic Lifecycle Service Asset Upload (LCS)

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, devops

I am uploading Dynamic Lifecycle Service Asset Upload (LCS) Asset in my release pipeline Currently I am working on Azure devops pipeline (Classic UI) I want to convert it to ymal file. while converting it to Ymal I'm not able to get Asset type* variable and its value. Also I'm not getting reference name and its value in the ymal file.

Can any one help me on this why I'm not able to get it or do I need to write explicitly in the ymal file..?
I'm getting only these much info when I convert it to ymal.

```yaml
steps:
- task: Dyn365FinOps.dynamics365-finops-tools.lcs-assetupload.LCSAssetUpload@0

  displayName: 'Upload Asset'

  inputs:

    serviceConnectionName: 'LCS Test'

    projectId: '$(ProjectId)'

    assetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/XXXXXX.zip'

    assetName: TestValidationAsset
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi there, is there any updates for this issue? Please check whether my answer can help you and feel free to comment~

Comment: Hi Jane, Need you help I want to deploy Dynamics Lifecycle Services (LCS) Asset Deployment to sandbox environment while deploying I want to simulate failure in package file or anywhere to test  Resume/ Rollback operation do you have any suggestion how i can archive this..? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of "Type of Asset" is not in the YAML file script, but is in its task settings.

Here is a Settings button in your pipeline before the task.

[image]

Click it and you will see a place to choose your "Type of asset", just like what you did in the classic UI pipeline.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it  helped me to get the value basically in ymal we have to define integer value  '10' for Software deployment package.